# How to add a GPU accelarator to CIS UBUNTU linux 20.04 on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

I am trying to set up a CIS Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Benchmark Level 1 on GCP with [this image](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/cis-public/cis-ubuntu-linux-2004-level-1?authuser=1&project=trinity-dev-200016) in marketplace.

I am able to get the image to launch with any CPU configuration but I am not able to add a GPU to a VM containing the same. Is there a way to do the same?

I am sure there is a method to implement it just not sure how do I find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deploy the image on a N1 instance, then stop it, edit and add NVIDIA Tesla T4.
You can try different combination, but not all instance types and regions can have a GPU.
For more information regarding GPU restriction check the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus?&_ga=2.170781095.-606233444.1631708747#restrictions).